# Compact Operators on Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Given $H$ an Hilbert space and $A:H\rightarrow H$ a compact operator with norm less than one.
Consider

$$B: L^2([0,1];H)\rightarrow L^2([0,1];H) $$
defined as

$(Bf)(x):=A[f(x)]$.

Is $B$ still a compact operator?

Comment: Please, do not use all caps in your title. Also, please share what you have done or tried for this question.

Comment: It's not a possible duplicate because in my case A is compact and not just bounded.

Comment: The conclusion is that a nonzero multiplication operator is not compact. Compactness of the $A : H\to H$ is not relevant to this conclusion.

Comment: @MichaelLee While I agree that your linked question can inspire counterexamples, I do not agree that this is a "duplicate".

Comment: Fair enough. There are similar questions (like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236669/no-nonzero-multiplication-operator-is-compact)) that perhaps cover the material of this question more closely, but have been marked as duplicates of the first question I linked.

Comment: There's still a fundamental difference in that all these other questions deal only with the Hilbert space $L^2(0,1)$, whereas this question introduces an arbitrary Hilbert space $H$, a compact operator on that space, and considers the space $L^2([0,1];H)$ of square integrable functions with values in $H$. Neither operator considered need be a multiplication operator, either.

Comment: Again, fair. It would probably be more appropriate to say while the question is not a duplicate, a very special case of the proposition is false due to results of other questions, and therefore the more general case is clearly false.

Comment: True, but I think only a very minor edit ("Is $B$ still a compact operator?" replaced with "Are there suitable conditions on $A,H$ that guarantee $B$ is a compact operator?") makes the linked question unhelpful, and so I think the closure here is inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. If $H=\mathbb R$, then $A$ is of the form $Ax=\lambda x$ for some $\lambda$. If $\lambda\neq0$, then $f\mapsto\lambda f$ is not compact on $L^2(0,1)$.